# Is it possible to create a date string, from a timestamp and a timezone offset?

Tags: php, date, localization, timezone

All the Date/Time extension is based on timezone strings such as "Europe/Amsterdam".

The dropdown I show to the user has one option per timezone offset, eg: "(UTC -3:00) Argentina, Brazil, French Guiana, Uruguay"

I don't think showing him a list with all the countries in the world would be appropiate, since the only thing that matters is the timezone offset.

Is it possible to create a localized date object, or date string, from something like '-2' (as the timezone offset) ??

**Answer**: date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unix_timestamp + $offset * 60 * 60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unix_timestamp + $offset * 60 * 60)

Answer (score 1):

You can feed date function the second argument using [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) . 
Smth like this :

`var_dump($endDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(0-2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2011)));`

Or using the [datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) like this :

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

---

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
# equivalent of GMT since Europe/Bucharest is +2 , we feed -2 for the hour
var_dump($endDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(date('h')-2, date('i'), date('s'), date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'))));
# equivalent of GMT+1 since Europe/Bucharest is +2 we feed -1 for the hour
var_dump($endDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(date('h')-1, date('i'), date('s'), date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'))));
```

you can allso feed +3 for the hour , taking Europe/Bucharest as the default timezone +3 would give the GMT +5 , you can allso set the default timezone Europe/London witch is equivalent of GMT0 then the user sends you +2 you will feed mktime with +2 for the hour witch will give you the equivalent of GMT+2 europe/bucharest .

Comment: I said I don't have the timezone strings. The user picks a timezone offset like '-2' or '+3'. I need to build the date with that.

Comment: see the edit , you clearly didn't understand what was happening

Comment: Okay, the mktime thing confused me, since I wanted to use a unix timestamp directly. Now I realized that I can do something like: date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp + $offset * 60*60). Thanks

Comment: yes , you can use it like that too , and i gues it will be a tad faster than my example too .